# Error An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to run my code as new thread and now I'm getting error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Deploy.Form1.textBox1' on line 59 foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "*"

```
namespace Deploy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                FolderBrowserDialog objFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                textBox1.Text = GetNetworkFolders(objFolderDialog);

                NewThread();
            }
        }

        public static string GetNetworkFolders(FolderBrowserDialog oFolderBrowserDialog)
        {
            Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType();
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("rootFolder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            fieldInfo.SetValue(oFolderBrowserDialog, (Environment.SpecialFolder)18);
            if (oFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return oFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
            static void Main( string[] args )
            {
             Thread t = new Thread( NewThread );
             t.Start();
            }

            static void NewThread()
            {
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));

                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text), true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless things have changed in recent version of .Net, you cannot interact directly with UI components from threads other than the original thread. I think you would have to use marshalling if you want to transfer between threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Invoke method on the textbox controls that you are trying to access in the new thread because of the exact reason that DeanOC stated. Try the following:

```
    string  directory = string.Empty;
    textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
       directory = textBox1.Text; // runs on UI thread
    });

    string  directory2 = string.Empty;
    textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
       directory = textBox2.Text; // runs on UI thread
    });
```

Comment: @user2489686, you need to add this code to the beginning of the NewThread method and use the string values instead of accessing the text property of the textboxes directly.